# Dynamic object creation with HashMap

Tags: java

I want to use a HashMap to dynamically create objects based on the key.

I have a Random Map Generator that stores the maps in 3D Arrays of Type `Integer[][][]`. Upon creation of the actual map I iterate through this array and based on the Integer I want to create the right block.

Example: `Integer[][][] map ... map[6][6][6] = 3;` 3 is a Earth-Block and now I want to initialize a new Block of this type and give it the right coordinates.

Currently I store my Bindings from Integer to Class in a `HashMap(Integer, String)` and create my objects like that:

```
int id = array[x][y][z];
String block_name = Blocks.map.get(id);

Block block = (Block) Class.forName(block_name).newInstance();
block.setPosition(x,y,z);
```

But I want to avoid `newInstance()` if possible.

I've never worked that dynamically with Java before and I couldn't find a solution like changing the HashMap to (Integer, Class) or something. I just need to create a new Object based upon the Integer.

Any ideas/solutions? Thanks in advance and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Maybe a map that matches together IDs and BlockFactorys, which have a static newInstance()-method. So you do `block = blockFactorys.get(id).newInstance()`. This would however generate lots of new classes. A BlockClass could even be its own factory. This would kill the additional classes.

Comment: Btw, it comes to my mind that this would better be placed on codereview-SE, because you have working code which simply needs to be refined.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidated by asker

> If you don't mind to use the same Block over and over again, simply do a mapping `Integer→Block`.

---

### Answer starts here

Otherwise, you could use some kind of factory-pattern.

You store a mapping `Integer→BlockFactory`, where BlockFactory is an instance of the Factpry corresponding Block. You then have a `newInstance(/*params*/)` method which would create a Block on runtime.

```
public DirtFactory extends BlockFactory
{
    @Override
    public Block newInstance(int x, int y /*...*/)
    {
        Dirt d = new Dirt();
        d.x = x; d.y = y; /*...*/
        /* do other stuff if necessary*/
        return d;
}
```

.

```
/*only the code from id to block */
HashMap<Integer,BlockFactory> mapping = new HashMap<>();

/*fill your HashMap with Instances of your BlockFactorys at the start of your game*/

int id = array [13][3][7];
Block b = mapping.get(id).newInstance(/*params*/);
```

Now you have your Block saved in `b`.
You will not come around a newInstance () in some way (a copy() is also some kind of newInstance() ). But I consider my solution better than using the Class-class.
If you want to save class-Definitions, you can embed the functionality of the Factory in the corresponding Block, however this gets messy very, *very* fast and is not recommended.

Note to programmers: I know this is not the nicest representation for the Factory-Pattern, but should do the trick here quite well.

Comment: I do mind using the same block over and over again, because if it was destroyed there would be quite a mess ;) Every block needs to be another object.

Comment: @Salor in this case refer to second part of the answer. I made a bit clearer were it starts ;)